# How do cross-browser, cross-device Password Managers work?

Tags: browser-addons, password-management, keepass, lastpass, dashlane

For no good reason, I use three different browsers on my laptop. Each has it's own built-in password manager, and if I have to update a password in one, I have to do it in the others.

I've read about some commercial password managers like Dashlane, KeePass, and Lastpass, but when I read their descriptions, there's something that's not clear to me.

I'd *like* a password manager to fill in the user name and password on each website (like the built-in ones do), but still retain only the current password regardless if I switch browsers.

Do they actually work this way?

(Bonus question: the built-in manager in Chrome manages the passwords for my Android phone too. Is that possible with the other managers?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I securely store and manage 180 passwords?](https://superuser.com/questions/432844/how-do-i-securely-store-and-manage-180-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they work that way (at least Keepass does).  Also, At minimum Keepass is not commercial - its free and open source.

Note that in addition to Keepass you will need (mainly free) plugins to get communication working between your browser and Keepass, so there is a bit of fiddling around involved initially.  (Also, for my plugin solution, Keepass/Kee provide its own system which works in addition to the internal password system in my browser)